# How can I get an attribute option id from its label?

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes

Magento 2.4: I have a custom product attribute called `shop_status`. It has two possible options:

- ACTIVE
- INACTIVE

I would like to get the option ID from the text label, eg:

`$id = $attribute->getOptionValue('ACTIVE');`

Is there any function to do this?

I know I can get a list of the options and loop through to find like so:

```
$attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get(
    'catalog_product',
    'shop_status'
);
$options = $attribute->getOptions();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    // If label == ACTIVE
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

> **Try Below Code:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productData = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById(12);// addd Product ID
echo $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('shop_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData);

OR

protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getLabelName($prdId)
{
    $productData = $this->productRepository->getById($prdId);// addd Product ID
    return $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('shop_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this requires a product with the attribute. I don't have that. I only have the attribute and the option label from which I want to get the option ID.

Comment: you need to pass only attribute code here. It's the return option label of a responsive product.